# Are requests for Skeptical Literature on specific subjects on topic?

Tags: discussion

Inspired by [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/revisions/16591/2), and it's subsequent reedited into [this form](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/revisions/16591/3)

The original form of the question did not comply with Skeptics rules, however Oddthinking reformatted the question into the form I linked to. I'm curious about whether the edited form is on topic, but more generally I'd like to ask; are requests for existing skeptical material on very specific subjects on topic?

I don't think that they are since they're not addressing a specific claim but are instead seeking literature recommendations, in this case debunking a book.

However I am uncertain because it is actually possible to answer this question in a fairly definitive way: he is requesting material debunking the specific claims of the book (claims that by themselves would be on-topic). He is, in a sense, requesting Skeptical responses to a claim by proxy. And since Skeptical responses to claims is the purpose of this site I'm not sure that the process being removed by 1 step actually invalidates it. Either the literature exists or it doesn't and a little research could find it.

*Obviously the original asker, or anyone who has read the book "The Cosmic Serpent" could edit this question to be fully on-topic by asking about the specific claims. However assuming that this doesn't happen, or that the asker really only wants reading recommendations, is this form of the question on-topic?*

Comment: My question is a little hard to explain clearly since the title of Oddtihnking's edit is very much an on-topic question. But the body of the question is still restricted to the original askers request - i.e. for reading material.

Comment: About this particular case, I changed the question from a request for reading material to a direct challenge of the claim. But, your question here is still a good one, and we should be able to answer it in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

From the FAQ/Help:

> Skeptics Stack Exchange is for **challenging unreferenced notable claims**, pseudoscience and biased results. ([*What topics can I ask about here*](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic))
>
> **If your question is not about a particular claim**, [...] the following sites may be better suited for your needs: (*Id*.)

The asker can also challenge several claims simultaneously. (*[What should we do with questions not directed to a claim?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2361/what-should-we-do-with-questions-not-directed-to-a-claim/2362#2362)*)

Regarding the title being on-topic, but the body not being on topic, we look to the body of the question for the claim and challenge, not the title. The title can even ask a question that the asker is not interested in, if it gives readers a reasonable idea what the whole question is about. (*https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2285/rejected-edit-review*)

The asker needs to **challenge a particular claim**, or several mutually exclusive claims simultaneously, and that challenge needs to come from the question body.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that questions that are purely asking for "skeptical reading material" (ugh, something about the way that sounds strikes me as being off) since they detract from the Q&A format and stand a strong likelihood of just ending up being a list of things with no real usefulness to anyone past that initial question.

However, on the Meta side of things, they might be on topic because I can see how that style of question might be useful to gather up enough information to be able to write a response to a question on the main site.